# Is it possible for an inequality constraint to be active at all feasible region in linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose we have an optimization problem

$\min f(x)$

s.t.      $ c_1(x) \ge 0$

with one constraint only.

Is there a nonlinear constraint (specific example) that is active at all feasible points? what if the constraint is linear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the given optimization problem the feasible set is $S := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\colon\; c_1(x) \geq0\}$. Assume that for all feasible points $x \in S$ the constraint $c_1$ is active, i.e.,
$$
x \in S \Leftrightarrow c_1(x) \geq 0 \Rightarrow c_1(x) = 0
$$
Then we are searching a function $c_1\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with $c_1(x) \geq 0 \Rightarrow c_1(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Thus, there are many possibilities on how to choose $c_1$. For example, $c_1(x) := -x_1^2$ would fit.